# Measuring peak memory usage of many processes

Tags: process, memory

I have a bash script that calls various other scripts, one of which has a bunch of commands that launch scripts inside a screen session like this:

```
screen -S $SESSION_NAME -p $f -X stuff "$CMD\n"
```

Will running my top script with /usr/bin/time -v capture the peak memory usage everything?  I want to have this script run as a cron job but I need to know how much memory it will take before I cause problems for other users on the machine.

Thanks

Comment: `time` will only give information for its children, and by *stuffing* a command into an existing screen session, that command will not be a child of your script, so will not be observed by `time`.  You might use another `time` when you start the screen session, but note that it only gives the max RSS of the biggest process.

Comment: @meuh Not even of the biggest one if it runs in background, see the  example in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes and no**, GNU time tries to show the summary/peak of everything.

You may check that using a small C program, say `mal.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long bytes;
    void *buf;

    bytes = atol(argv[1]) * 1024;
    buf = malloc(bytes);
    memset(buf, 0, bytes);
    printf("");
    return 0;
}
```

And see:

```
$ gcc mal.c -o mal
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%M" sh -c "./mal 5000"
5452
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%M" sh -c "./mal 10000"
10452
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%M" sh -c "./mal 5000; ./mal 10000"
10452
```

**But** as mentioned in the getrusage(2) man page (Linux), this is the max RSS of any single child process, not the instantaneous cumulative RSS of a tree of processes, all simultaneously using memory

In other words it does not summarize parallel or background processes, as you can see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f "%M" sh -c "./mal 1000000 & ./mal 5000"
5452
```

This also implies that you need to run `time` inside of your screen session to measure $CMD and not only screen.

**FYI** the difference between the shell built-in is that the time binary can't directly summarize pipes or functions:

```
$ time /bin/sleep 1 | /bin/sleep 2
 real 2.00
 user 0.00
 sys 0.00

$ /usr/bin/time -p  /bin/sleep 1 | /bin/sleep 2
 real 1.00
 user 0.00
 sys 0.00
```